# Wrap Around Grid - errors on east/west only

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, modulus

I have four methods that check whether or not a given grid location is next to an occupied location (value of 1). The grid is assumed to wrap around, ie, if in a 50x50 grid[0][1] is the given location and grid[49][1] is occupied, the method should return true/ My checkNorth and checkEast method are working fine, but I get an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: -1 error for either the south or west methods every time I run the program. I checked my math and I think it should work - am I using the modulo incorrectly, or am I missing something else?
EDIT: Clarified the wrapping criterion, word use correction.

```
boolean checkWest(int indexA, int indexB)
{
    if (indexA-1 > 0)
    {
        if (grid[indexA-1][indexB] == 1)
            {
            return true;
            }
    }
    if (indexA-1 < 0)
        {
        if (grid[(indexA-1)%width][indexB] == 1)
            {return true;}
        else return false;
        }
return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple problems.  First, Java arrays are zero-indexed, which means that the first element is at index 0.  So it's okay to check `grid[indexA-1][indexB]` when `indexA-1` is equal to 0.  Second, you're not properly handling when indexA equals 0.  Here is my implementation.  I also simplified the logic a bit.

```
boolean checkWest(int indexA, int indexB)
{
    if (indexA > 0) 
        return grid[indexA - 1][indexB] == 1;
    else
        return grid[width + indexA - 2][indexB] == 1;
}
```

EDIT:  I'm pretty sure I butchered the math with the second return statement.  It should be right now...

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. Two questions:
1. If Java arrays are zero-indexed, should the first if statement read (indexA >= 0)?
2. I understand what's going on with [width + indexA - 2], but why is it preferable to using a modulo?

Comment: @r.ree 1. If you use `indexA >= 0`, then you will end up trying to read your grid at index -1, because `0 - 1 == -1`.  This will give you an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.  2. This might be up to personal preference.  I think the math is simpler.  As long as `indexA` is never so low that `width + indexA - 2` is less than 0, it should work fine.